# best way to draw complicated table iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, custom-controls

im looking for an idea how to draw complicated table in UIView. the table should be very similar to what we can achievie with html table but i cant use UIWebView. So the main goals is to have multirow header with span column in the header.

I would be very gratefull for any ideas or point where to look for info.

best regards

Comment: Why can't you use _UIWebView_? It would be a natural choice.

Comment: ok, I've test UIWebView a bit. Its looks much much better then what I've achieved with CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(). The only question I have now is if it lead to memory problems if I will use a lot of UIWebView in my application ?

Comment: I suggest going with UIWebView and see how far you can push it. Use Instruments to profile your memory use. My guess is that if you are targeting the iPhone 3GS/iPod touch 3rd gen and newer devices, you are not going to run into any memory issues. Trying to do any sort of complex text layout otherwise will require the use of Core Text, which is really difficult and tricky to deal with.